# Disjoint subsets problem complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete

Is the decision problem below NP-complete?

Given sets $S_1, ... , S_n$, as well as bounds $b_1, ... , b_n$, is it possible to pick pairwise disjoint subsets $U_1, ... , U_n$ such that $U_i \subset S_i$ and $|U_i| \geqslant b_i$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chandra Chekuri's comment made me think about casting the problem as a maximum flow problem (solvable in polynomial time):

- $\forall i$, have a  vertex $v_{i}$, connected to the source by an edge with capacity $b_i$.
- $\forall i$, $ \forall e \in S_i$, have a vertex $v_{e}$, connected to all $v_j$ such that $e \in S_j$ with capacity $1$, and connected to the sink with capacity $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Create a bipartite graph:

- For every element $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i$, introduce a corresponding vertex $u(x)$.
- For every set $S_i$, introduce a corresponding vertex $v(S_i)$.
- Connect vertex $u(x)$ to vertex $v(S_i)$ by an edge, if and only if $x\in S_i$.

Then your problem essentially asks, whether there exists a subset $F$ of the edges, so that

- every vertex $u(x)$ is incident to at most one edge in $F$, and
- every vertex $v(S_i)$ is incident to at least $b_i$ edges in $F$.

This is an instance of the so-called $f$-factor problem, and hence solvable in polynomial time.
See for instance the book *"Matching Theory"* by László Lovász and Michael D. Plummer.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to see this via network flow that generalizes bipartite matching  problems. Matching Theory book is rather old and hard to find. See Kleinberg-Tardos book or Jeff Erickson's  notes on network flow and applications. https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/